# How do I change the class of a button I just clicked without being specific?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the class of a button that is clicked without being specific.

**Not what I want:**

`$('#buttonid').addClass('active')`

I want to grab the context of the button being clicked and automatically add a class to it, regardless of which button was clicked.

Ideally I'd like a situation where I have an onClick function that I assign to each button, and it will change the class (among other things) for only the buttons that have that function.

Something like:

**Pseudocode**

```
onClick function() {
  thisButton.addClass('active')
}
```

Comment: Easiest way ist to add a class to every button that shall fire the function. Otherwise you can use the html tag `onclick=""`. Here is an example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp. Another way would be to listen for clicks on button (`$("button").on("click", function() {});`) and check if the given classes or ids are in a pre defined list.

Comment: if you have the ability to add `onClick` code, can you add a `class` that would allow you to identify multiple buttons that would be affected by the code?

Comment: In my current setup, I'm using React, which encourages you to use onClick, however this is a problem that I've come across before even without React. The idea of a class works, but still seems to add an unnecessary step that makes things more difficult to change than one function or one onClick, especially if we're working with hundreds of these possible buttons.

Comment: Which specific buttons do you mean?

Comment: _"I also don't want this to work with every button, only specific ones.

Ideally I'd like a situation where I have an onClick function that I assign to each button, and it will change the class (among other things) for only the buttons that have that function."_ Not certain what issue is?

Comment: @guest271314 Just updated the question to be more specific. Thank you!

Comment: @CalebAnthony See posted Answer. Note, Answer by @Mohamed-Ted should return similar result; though approach at posted Answer does not toggle `className`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the event listener to the element containing the buttons. The handler function will receive the click event which will contain a `target` propriety that point to the element that triggered the event. You can compare `e.target` to make sure you have the element you need. (I used `dataset` in my snippet)

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");

container.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (target.dataset.action == 'click') {
    target.classList.toggle('clicked');
  }
})
```

```css
button.clicked {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button data-action="click">Click Me</button>
  <button data-action="click">Click Me</button>
  <button data-action="click">Click Me</button>
  <button>Nothing Will Happen</button>
  <button data-action="click">Click Me</button>
  <button data-action="click">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Note: the snippet is for IE9+, there are polyfills for older browsers.

Comment: I like that you can manipulate the target of the action, that's what I'm looking for. However, I don't like the fact that you still need to have a unique ID on the parent container.

In my situation, there are going to be a variable number of containers, and the thought of running a loop every time containers are changed and adding/removing event listeners seems dirty.

Comment: @CalebAnthony in that case you can set the parent container to the body element, that will capture all click events, and you can you e.target to determine your actions. You will only need to set the event listener once.

Comment: Is there a downside to setting an event listener on every click action in the entire body container?

Comment: that will depend on how much it cost to find out weather the triggering element is the right one or not. checking an attribute is not a big cost.

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch the DOM changes. This short example uses [`MutationObserver()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) object:

(Note: I don't know what 'specific' buttons you've meant.)

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var buttons = [];




/**
 * When a button is clicked
 */
function buttonClickEvent() {
    this.className = this.className === 'active' ? '' : 'active';
}



/**
 * Iterate each button in the 'buttons' {Array}.
     * if callback returns false, the loop breaks.
 */
function filterButtons(callback) {
    for (var i = 0, btn; (btn = buttons[i++]) && (callback(btn) !== false););
}



/**
 * Update buttons in certain collections.
 * @param {HTMLCollection, else ...} addedNodes
 * @param {HTMLCollection, else ...} removedNodes
 * @param {Boolean} ignoreBtnCheck
 */
function updateButtons(addedNodes, removedNodes, ignoreBtnCheck) {
    for (var i = 0, el; el = addedNodes[i++];) {
        if (ignoreBtnCheck || el.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'BUTTON') {
            var found = false;

            filterButtons(function(btn) {
                if (btn === el) {
                    found = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            if (!found) {
                el.addEventListener('click', buttonClickEvent);
                buttons.push(el);
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; el = removedNodes[i++];) {
        if (el.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'BUTTON') {
            filterButtons(function(btn) {
                if (btn === el) {
                    buttons.splice(i, 1);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }

}




/**
 * Create a 'MutationObserver' to handle
 events like DOMInsertedNode, etc.
 */
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    if (mutations[0].addedNodes.length || mutations[0].removedNodes.length)
        updateButtons(mutations[0].addedNodes, mutations[0].removedNodes);
});




/**
 * Observe DOM changes in 'body'.
 */
observer.observe(body, { childList: true, subtree: true });




/**
 * Update at least once each button in 'body'
 */
updateButtons(body.getElementsByTagName('button'), [], true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for..of` loop, `document.querySelectorAll()` `Element.addEventListener`, `event.target` to reference current clicked element

```css
.selected {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<button>click</button>
<button>click</button>
<button>click</button>
<button>click</button>
<script>
  for (let button of document.querySelectorAll("button")) {
    button.addEventListener("click", e => e.target.classList.add("selected"))
  }
</script>
```